# In Plotly, output an empty graph and fill it out based on user's choice from dropdown menues

Tags: python, plotly

I have a working code for the following:
There are 3 dropdown menus.

1. to select an X value
2. to select a Y value
3. to select a graph type (Bar chart, Line chart, or Bubble chart).

Here is my json file:

```
{
"Names": {
    "0": "Alice",
    "1": "Robert",
    "2": "Garry",
    "3": "Nate",
    "4": "Karen",
    "5": "Nick"
},
"Address": {
    "0": "21 Main St",
    "1": "19 Third St",
    "2": "4 Church St",
    "3": "5 High St",
    "4": "9 Elm St",
    "5": "06 Washingtom St"
},
"AreaCode": {
    "0": "777",
    "1": "421",
    "2": "768",
    "3": "345",
    "4": "888",
    "5": "123"
}}
```

Here is a python file:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


df_data = pd.read_json("test.json")


button_x_list = []
button_y_list = []
button_graphs_list = []

colnames=df_data.keys()

for col in colnames:
    button_x_list.append(
        dict(
            method="update",
            label=col,
            visible=True,
            args=[
                {"x": [df_data[col]]},
                {"xaxis": {"title": col}},
            ],
        )
    )

    button_y_list.append(
        dict(
            method="update",
            label=col,
            visible=True,
            args=[
                {"y": [df_data[col]]},
                {"yaxis": {"title": col}},
            ],
        )
    )


button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(
        args=["type", "line"],
        label="Line",
        method="restyle"
    )
)

button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(
        args=["type", "bar"],
        label="Bar",
        method="restyle"
    )
)

button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(
        args=["type", "bubble"],
        label="Bubble",
        method="restyle"
    )
)

button_x_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_x_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.03,
    y=1.08,
)

button_y_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_y_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.23,
    y=1.08,
)

button_graphs_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_graphs_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.46,
    y=1.08,
)

annotation_x = dict(
    text="X:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)
annotation_y = dict(
    text="Y:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0.2,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)
annotation_graphs = dict(
    text="Graph:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0.4,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)



fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=df_data["Names"], y=df_data["AreaCode"], mode="markers"))
fig.update_layout(
updatemenus=[button_x_dict, button_y_dict, button_graphs_dict], annotations=[annotation_x, annotation_y, annotation_graphs],
title="Plotly Demo",
xaxis={"title":"Names"}, yaxis={"title":"AreaCode"}
)

fig.show()
```

It works well but there is one thing I'm trying to change.
Here I'm hardcoding the initial type of the graph(Scatter) and the values(df_data["Names"] and df_data["AreaCode"]):

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=df_data["Names"], y=df_data["AreaCode"], mode="markers"))
```

What I want instead is an empty graph, and only after the user selects all the parameters from the dropdown menus, then the values are displayed on the graph.

Is there a way to do so without creating additional dependencies?
I've seen Plotly FigureWidget but it doesn't work as it creates an additional dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=pd.Series(dtype=object), y=pd.Series(dtype=object), mode="markers"))
```

That way it starts out with an empty series. In my full code (below) I also added a blank button to the drop down with null data so the user doesn't think they're actually looking at Names, AreaCode, or Address. Lastly I started out with the x-axis and y-axis unlabeled (blank string).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


df_data = pd.read_json("test.json")


button_x_list = []
button_y_list = []
button_graphs_list = []

colnames = df_data.keys()

null_x = dict(
    method="update",
    label="",
    visible=True,
    args=[
        {"x": ["" for _ in range(len(df_data))]},
        {"xaxis": {"title": ""}},
    ],
)

null_y = dict(
    method="update",
    label="",
    visible=True,
    args=[
        {"y": ["" for _ in range(len(df_data))]},
        {"yaxis": {"title": ""}},
    ],
)

button_x_list.append(null_x)
button_y_list.append(null_y)

for col in colnames:
    button_x_list.append(
        dict(
            method="update",
            label=col,
            visible=True,
            args=[
                {"x": [df_data[col]]},
                {"xaxis": {"title": col}},
            ],
        )
    )

    button_y_list.append(
        dict(
            method="update",
            label=col,
            visible=True,
            args=[
                {"y": [df_data[col]]},
                {"yaxis": {"title": col}},
            ],
        )
    )


button_graphs_list.append(dict(args=["type", "line"], label="Line", method="restyle"))

button_graphs_list.append(dict(args=["type", "bar"], label="Bar", method="restyle"))

button_graphs_list.append(
    dict(args=["type", "bubble"], label="Bubble", method="restyle")
)

button_x_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_x_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.03,
    y=1.08,
)

button_y_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_y_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.23,
    y=1.08,
)

button_graphs_dict = dict(
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    xanchor="left",
    yanchor="top",
    visible=True,
    buttons=button_graphs_list,
    pad={"r": 15, "t": 10},
    x=0.46,
    y=1.08,
)

annotation_x = dict(
    text="X:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)
annotation_y = dict(
    text="Y:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0.2,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)
annotation_graphs = dict(
    text="Graph:",
    showarrow=False,
    x=0.4,
    y=1.05,
    xanchor="left",
    xref="paper",
    yref="paper",
    align="left",
    yanchor="top",
)

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(x=pd.Series(dtype=object), y=pd.Series(dtype=object), mode="markers")
)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[button_x_dict, button_y_dict, button_graphs_dict],
    annotations=[annotation_x, annotation_y, annotation_graphs],
    title="Plotly Demo",
    xaxis={"title": ""},
    yaxis={"title": ""},
)

fig.show()
```

Here is what it looks like initially:

[image: Initial view]

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is exactly what I was looking for!